# Check is finish async and await behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, async

I am trying to understand the `async` and `await`.Now i want to apply `async` and `await` keyword in my current project.My process structure are:

```
//DataAccess 
Private List<Users> GetAllUsers()
{
   .... ;
   return List<Users>
}

//UI
List<Users> UserList=new List<Users>();
private async void Ok_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //I want to select all user ant assign to UserList but currently it not use.
    UserList=await BindUser();    
}

private async Task<List<Users>> BindUser()
{
  List<Users> model=await Task.Run(()=>GetAllUsers());
  return model;
}
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //I want to use UserList here and want to validate process   
}
```

Problem is if i click save click button quickly,`UserList` count are `0`(Actually `UserList` record are over 100,000).So I want to check `BindUser()` process is finish or not before doing validation process in `Save_Click()`. Please let me known for best solution and help me to understand `async` and `await` keyword. Thanks.

Comment: The very best resource that I know of to fully understand `async` in C# is [this Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.120).aspx).  In the meantime, a better place to ask your code troubleshooting question is Stack Overflow (we don't do code troubleshooting here, sorry).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you for you link and i will noted you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ViewModel and a RelayCommand

Set the datacontext of your Window/UserControl to the viewmodel and bind the Button to the ICommand on your view model in xaml.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099312/is-asynchronous-version-of-relaycommand-required-in-order-to-run-async-methods-c

If you are using an MVVM framework they often provide a DelegateCommand class which will let you easily create ICommands.

The CanExecute function will disable the button when the command cant execute.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `async`?

Comment: yes. follow this advice and you will have an async method fired when you click your button and the button will disable while it is running

Comment: I guess I had to click your link to get the full story.  That's not exactly the best form for Stack Exchange answers.

Comment: yes, but its an internal link. plus I figure the OPs problem is not so much the details of async, but that they are fighting the system with async event handlers in the code behind